# ADO.NET or OLE DB for MonetDB

Tags: ssas, monetdb

I am looking for either **ADO.NET** (ActiveX Data Objects) or native **OLE DB** (Object Linking and Embedding, Database) provider for MonetDB. - https://www.monetdb.org/

I am trying to access `MonetDB` from within `MS Analytical services`, but `SSAS` does not support `odbc` connections.
so far I found 3 dead links:

```
https://monetdbprovider.codeplex.com/ 
http://www.nuget.org/packages/MonetDBClient/ 
https://code.google.com/archive/p/monetdb-net/
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It has an ODBC Driver that you can use via OdbcConnection() et al.

Comment: Are you doing SSAS Multidimensional or Tabular or do you care? What version of SSAS?

Comment: As long as i understand we are using it as Multidimensional. I am looking for something like dotConnect for MySQL by Devart, but for monetdb.